# Django Model Design: User Owned Object Instances, Name Not Unique

Tags: django, model-view-controller, django-models, model

I'm relatively new to Django model design and now I want to do something like this.

Suppose Alice has three dogs named Road-runner, Pinky, and Kiwi. 
Bob has one cat called Spinner and also owns Pinky with Alice together.

So the name of the object Pet is not unique. A pet can have more than one owner. I think this is many-to-many relationship.

Now in my views I would like to list out their own pets. How do I implement it? I know it's related to user auth and foreign keys and stuff, if someone could point out some directions or clear explanation that will be great.

I have now:

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Owner(models.Model):
    pet = models.ForeignKey(Pet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Should I put `owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` in Pet object instead? What if the website is all about pets and owners is just information attached to the pet.

Intuitively either way I'm leaning toward putting `owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` in Pet object is the right way.

And then how to restrict users to their own object? If the pet is renamed, it has to be filtered out by it's owner info so that we don't rename other's pet.

Thank you for you time.

EDIT:

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Owner(models.Model):
    pet = models.ManyToManyField(Pet)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the name of the object Pet is not unique. A pet can have more than one owner. I think this is many-to-many relationship.

Sounds very much like it, but what you have created is not a many to many relationship. It should be something like this:

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Owner(models.Model):
    pet = models.ManyToManyField(Pet)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Reference for ManyToMany field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField

note that I have added a one to one between Owner and User. That would allow you to

```
@login_required
def my_pets(request):
    Pet.objects.filter(owner__user=request.user)
```

Note that these are guidelines. You will need to fill it up with your code as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you! It suddenly becomes much clearer, I could't wrap my head around and think about some weird implementations. I saw someone doing this `user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, blank=True, related_name="pet_user")`, is it the same thing or related to you OneToOneField line?

Comment: It's it's actually the recommended way of doing it. But I thought you would find it harder to digest. In my example you just need to add `import django.contrib.auth.models User` to your models file

Comment: But that blank=True, and related_name part can be left out.(ie that part in the solution you saw elsehwere is redundant)

Comment: Use `user = models.OneToOneField(User)` or `user = models.ForeignKey(User)`?

Comment: Sorry if a pet can have more than one owner it should be ForeignKey